# VBA Delete column where first cell is a string of array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an excel file in which I would like delete columns that aren't useful.

Say I have 4 columns: 'ID', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Job'. What I'm trying to do is delete all columns that aren't 'ID' and 'Job'.

I tried using the Range.Find method, but there's obviously something I'm getting wrong.

Any help appreciated

```
myArray = Array("ID", "Job")
'Delete columns which title aren't in myArray
For j = mycol To 1 Step -1 'col by col
    For k = 0 To 4 'for each element in myArray
        ' Delete col where no elements of myArray are present.
        Columns(j).Delete
    Next k
Next j
```

EDIT:
By columns names, I mean the first row of each column. So A1=ID, B1=Name etc.

Comment: what do you mean by column name? is it just a header in cell in certain row or you are using Tables (ListObjects)?

Comment: @KazimierzJawor By columns names, I mean the first row of each column. So A1=ID, B1=Name etc.

Comment: @Daniel Mc check the code in my answer below, let me know if it that's what you meant in your post

Comment: @ShaiRado That's exactly what I meant. I can't believe I didn't find something so obvious. Thanks

Comment: @DanielMc you're welcome

Comment: @ShaiRado Sorry, I prefer Kazmierz' method. Hope you can forgive me ;)

Comment: @DanielMc it's ok, it's a nice and cleaner answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could try with something easier:

```
For j = myCol To 1 Step -1 'col by col
    'check if column name is in array
    If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(1, j), myArray, 0)) Then
        Columns(j).Delete
    End If

Next j
```

Comment: That's a very nice method, didn't know it existed!

Comment: @KazimierzJawor  it is a nice and cleaner answer

Answer (score 0):

The code below will loop through all columns (according to your `mycol` value), and checks if the header in the first row matches any of the elements inside `myArray` array.

```
Sub DeleteColumns_NotinArray()

Dim myArray
Dim j As Long, k As Long, mycol As Long
Dim ColHeadrFound   As Boolean

myArray = Array("ID", "Job")

' just for my testing
mycol = 10

'Delete columns which title aren't in myArray
For j = mycol To 1 Step -1 'col by col

    ' reset flag
    ColHeadrFound = False
    For k = 0 To UBound(myArray) 'for each element in myArray
        If Cells(1, j).Value = myArray(k) Then
            ColHeadrFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next k
    ' Delete column where no elements of myArray are present
    If ColHeadrFound = False Then
        Columns(j).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If

Next j


End Sub
```